# How to search in Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

E.g. I'm building a real estate catalog. I need, well, bunch of properties and search by parameters like number of living rooms, city, area on the map, price range etc. The number of possible combinations here can easily exceed 200 indexes limit.

Or this is some kind of tag-based search. Number of variations here is nearly infinite.

If I understood it correctly, Cloud Datastore is not capable for such cases. But from my experience nearly all apps I was working on require such functionality. So, is Cloud Datastore suitable only for straight forward single-key search only? Plus Search API can handle full-text search. But that's all. That seems not right, so i assume I'm missing some fundamental point here.

May be there are some additional services for indexing? Or architectural solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, Cloud Datastore suitable only for straight forward single-key
>   search only?

Obviously not - you can use up to 200 composite indexes. And any number of the implicit indexes that the datastore keeps for each indexed property.

That may not be enough for some apps, I admit. In that case some other solution would probably be needed. Maybe even a hybrid combining the datastore with some other indexing technique? Not sure, I didn't try one yet as I didn't yet encounter such need.

But IMHO in your particular example you could make it fit in the 200 limit without a significant loss in practical functionality. Simply by not offering all the possible combinations - are they all really, really needed? Personally I'd find the ability to do more than a few dozens (let alone 200) *different kinds* of searches in a real estate application rather cluttering/overwhelming.

For example - does it make sense to search by either of price range, number of bedrooms or city only without specifying the other 2 parameters? Maybe for the curious, but IMHO without a real practical use. If you agree then simply requiring all 3 parameters instead of allowing any combination of them will effectively reduce your total number of required composite indexes to 1/8 of the original.

Or maybe the ability of sorting results in both ascending and descending order is not that critical - you can half the number of composite indexes for every parameter you sort by in only one direction. Sorting by more than just a few properties can also be of little value in the highly subjective real estate context. Less sorting combinations - fewer composite indexes.

Take a closer look at the number of parameters and the number of combinations that make practical sense. Cut what is not absolutely needed, maybe you can find a decent-enough compromise which doesn't require you to go to a more complicated approach.